# Plesk - What are these modules?

Tags: plesk, parallels

I had to remove php-mysql and install php-mysqlnd to fix some dependency issues, an I noticed these were removed also:

[Plesk Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPES7.png)

Does anyone know what these are? And will not having them cause any issues? I can't reinstall them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is modules of Horde webmail and internal Plesk PHP stuff. So, it is highly recommended to install it back via autoinstaller and, probably, running bootstrapper.sh --repair.

Right now your Plesk cannot serve webmail, and cannot configure PHP